# Can I make "static redirects" using symlinks in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, symbolic-link

I'm overhauling a site to use a new URL structure, but don't want the old URLs to 404, instead redirect to the new content.

To complicate things, this is on a shared host where `.htaccess` is the only configuration allowed. There are a *lot* of old URLs, enough that stuffing them all into `.htaccess` would be a bad move.

I know the `RewriteRule` directives require `FollowSymLinks` to be on—does that mean I can make a bunch of symlinks at the locations of the old URLs, that point to their new locations? Would that get Apache to emit a redirect to the new locations?

Answer (score 0):

No, a symlink is invisible in the URL.  It'll show the old URL with the new page, but then you'll have two copies of links.

Can you have the application redirect the URLs?  Are there a lot of actual links out there? Or are they just search engine results?  You could use canonical links for search engines if you decide to still use symlinks. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: It's a static web server that gets generated offline and uploaded. I might go with both the symlinks and the canonical links if nothing else will work.